# Make a simple DOM attribute a one-way binding one from a directive

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

Clearly my goal is to make an element as `<input type="text" placeholder="example" />` look likes `<input type="text" [placeholder]="'example'" />` after using an angular directive as

```
import { Directive, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[placeholder]'
})
export class PlaceholderDirective {
  @HostBinding('placeholder') placeholder:string;
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

But I don't really now how I could take the firstly set `placeholder="A placeholder"` in a `[placeholder]`without having an `undefined` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I answered myself by asking and writing the question, but here it is for those who'll ask themselves this:
I imported `ElementRef` to access the original placeholder value and set it in the `constructor` directly!

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[placeholder]'
})
export class PlaceholderDirective{
  @HostBinding('placeholder') placeholder:string;
  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.placeholder = elementRef.nativeElement.placeholder;
  }
}
```